# render nested arrays with react by display key only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested array and I would like to render this array with JSX code such that key like array1 should be display once and the text should be displayed as list and then continue the same loop with the next array. I have tried using map function and for loop but could not achieve success.

```
sampleArray : [{"array1": [ {"text": "abc"},{"text": "def"}, {"text": "ghi"}],
               "array2":[{"text": "efg"}, {"text": "fgh"}]]
```

Please suggest me map function to iterate over this array to render into JSX code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I don't know if you made a mistake in your object, but here are two versions of this implementation with your object and with my update:

Ignore typings did it in TypeScript

```
export const Test = ({ className }: Test) => {
  const sampleArray = [
    {
      array1: [{ text: 'abc' }, { text: 'def' }, { text: 'ghi' }],
      array2: [{ text: 'efg' }, { text: 'fgh' }],
    },
  ]

  const sampleArray2 = [
    {
      array1: [{ text: 'abc' }, { text: 'def' }, { text: 'ghi' }],
    },
    {
      array2: [{ text: 'efg' }, { text: 'fgh' }],
    },
  ]
  return (
    <>
      {/* YOUR VERSION */}
      <div>
        {Object.keys(sampleArray[0]).map((key) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div id="title">{key}</div>
              {sampleArray[0].map((item) => {
                return <div>{item.text}</div>
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
      {/* UPDATED VERSION */}
      <div>
        {sampleArray2.map((key) => {
          const title = Object.keys(key)[0]
          return (
            <div>
              <div id="title">{title}</div>
              {key[title].map((item) => {
                return <div>{item.text}</div>
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the version 2. I have changed my data structure and It worked.